# SyntaxError: Unexpected token when running selenium-javascript tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, npm, webdriver

I've been doing selenium with `Java`for years. However, now I'm trying to write Selenium scripts using `javascript`. I used following guide to learn JavaScript with Selenium.

[Guide](https://help.crossbrowsertesting.com/selenium-testing/getting-started/javascript/)

However, when I tried `npm install selenium-webdriver@3.6` in my command prompt, following error displays.

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\Proffessional\FMClarity\Selenium\package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\Proffessional\FMClarity\Selenium\package.json'
npm WARN Selenium No description
npm WARN Selenium No repository field.
npm WARN Selenium No README data
npm WARN Selenium No license field.

+ selenium-webdriver@3.6.0
added 30 packages from 69 contributors and audited 34 packages in 8.086s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

And then I tried following simple script,

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
                           withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.firefox() 
                            .build();

driver.get('https://github.com/i18next/i18next-parser/issues/86');
```

I tried run this script using `node sample.js`.
But following error shows,

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

This might not be a very good question. However, even if I have years of experience in Java, I'm new to JavaScript.

Any kind of help may be appreciated
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are missing the closing **`)`** in the line:

```
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
               withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.firefox() 
                .build();
```

Change it to:

```
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
               withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.firefox()) 
                .build();
```